# default collapsible group in handson table

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

How to make my handson table group to collapsible by default. It is opened by default

I have below code js and html code.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6jme16m/)

```
function getCarData() {
        return [ [ 'col1', "val2", "val3", "val4", "=SUM(E2:E4)" ],
                [ 4, 0, 3, 2, '=SUM(A2,B2,C2,D2)' ],
                [ 4, 0, 3, 2, '=SUM(A2,B2,C2,D2)' ],
                [ 4, 0, 3, 2, '=SUM(A2,B2,C2,D2)' ]
                ];
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('example1'), hot; 


    hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data : getCarData(),
        colHeaders : true,
        rowHeaders : true,
        contextMenu : true,
        manualColumnResize: true,
         minSpareRows: 1,
          groups: [
            {
              rows: [1, 3]
            }
         ],
        formulas : true,
        columns: [ { type: 'numeric'},
                     { type: 'numeric'},{ type: 'numeric' },{ type: 'numeric' },{ type: 'text',readOnly: true}]

    });
```

Comment: There isn't any api in handsontable to collapse the groups by default

Comment: aren't there any alternate way to do? I have also tried by triggering click event, but it wasn't worked

Comment: do mean you want to table to start collapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't really any built-in functionality to accomplish what you are looking for, there is a hackish workaround that I have used in the past.
Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fk4uohjk/

As you can see, one of the groups is collapsed when the page loads.  This is due to the following line:
`hot.runHooks("beforeOnCellMouseDown", {"target": $("#htCollapseRowsFromLevel-1")[0]});`

The `beforeOnCellMouseDown` hook is expecting a mouse event as the first parameter, but instead we can just give it a dictionary with the target attribute set to the group button dom element that corresponds to the group we want to collapse.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, this worked for me. There is one issue here I am not able to hide column headers with "hot.updateSettings({colHeaders: false});" , That I was able to to before putting your line of code : "  hot.runHooks("beforeOnCellMouseDown", {"target": $("#htCollapseRowsFromLevel-1")[0]});"

Comment: Looking into the [handsontable source code](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/b59808fea3b07a8ae11e46476b53c21316fb697b/src/plugins/grouping/grouping.js), it appears that the `stopImmediatePropagation` function is being called on the previously-mentioned mouse event.  Since it is absent in our dictionary, an error is raised which causes problems down the line.  Here is an updated fiddle that shows what needs to be done to work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fk4uohjk/1/

Comment: with your updated fiddle it collapse only one group since you have mentioned like that

Comment: Yes, you need to update the selector to indicate which controls to activate, with one `runHooks` call per group.  In my fiddle, you can collapse all groups like so: `hot.runHooks("beforeOnCellMouseDown", {stopImmediatePropagation: function(){}, target: $("div#htCollapse-r1.htVerticalGroup.htCollapseButton")[0]});
  hot.runHooks("beforeOnCellMouseDown", {stopImmediatePropagation: function(){}, target: $("div#htCollapse-r2.htVerticalGroup.htCollapseButton")[0]});`  But the selectors you use will likely vary.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the parameters in hot, which columns you don't want to resize i.e:
If you want to resize only the first 3 columns you may do:

```
  manualRowResize: true,
    ...
    colWidths: [, , , x, x],
//x can be any colWidth number
   });
```

If you want the first and fourth column

```
  manualRowResize: true,
    ...
    colWidths: [, x, x, , x],
   });
```